# Distance from a 3d point to x-axis

Tags: multivariable-calculus

How do I find the formula for the shortest distance between points
(a , b, c) and the x-axis. 
The answer I came up with was 
sqrt((1-a)^2+b^2+c^2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why, of course it is $\sqrt{b^{2}+c^{2}}$. Translation alongside $x$ axis does not alter the distance.

Another method can be $|\{a,b,c\}\times\{1,0,0\}|$ which yield the same answer